# Getting from Salt Lake City airport to Park City by public transport on a weekend night

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, utah, salt-lake-city, park-city

I've looked at the [Wikivoyage Get In section for Park City](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Park_City_%28Utah%29#Get_in) but it didn't have any helpful information. I'll be arriving in Salt Lake City airport and need to get to Park City but would rather not take a taxi, if possible. **Are there any sensible public transport options?**

Edit: As @choster points out, there are buses in the week from the airport to the Central bus station on [bus lines 453](http://www.rideuta.com/mc/?page=Bus-BusHome-Route453), and [454](http://www.rideuta.com/mc/?page=Bus-BusHome-Route454) but they do not run on Saturday or Sunday.

[Train 704 (green line)](http://www.rideuta.com/ridinguta/routes/schedule.aspx?abbreviation=704&dir=0&service=3&signup=188) goes to Arena Station. From there you take the 701 (blue line) to the Central station.

However, the last 704 on a Sunday evening is at 07:58 PM.

Comment: Check out RideUTA.com . There appear to be several bus routes from the airport to Salt Lake Central Station, and from there Route 902 terminates at Park City Old Town Transit Center.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm traveling on a Sunday and it appears that the buses going from the airport to the Central station don't run on Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: While this may not be helpful, I have several times gotten very cheap rental cars ($20/day) on weekend rates at SLC.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see on the official UTA website, it is impossible to get farther than Salt Lake City on a Sunday night.

1. It *is* possible to take the 704 to the Arena station as the [last train departs at 11:16PM on a Sunday night.](http://www.rideuta.com/ridinguta/routes/schedule.aspx?abbreviation=704&dir=0&service=3&signup=200)
2. However the only public bus to Park City is the [902 line](http://www.rideuta.com/mc/?page=Bus-BusHome-Route902), which doesn't run on the weekends.

Therefore you could either get a cheap hotel in Salt Lake City and wait until the morning or take a cab from the city center.